# R equivalent of the Matlab spy function

Tags: r, matlab, sparse-matrix

In Matlab, there is a function named spy, which displays the structure of a sparse matrix. It creates a plot of the matrix' dimensions where each entry that has a nonzero value is colored. Is there an equivalent function in R?

Comment: Can you include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with a sample R object that you wish to plot?

Comment: As an aside, the Matlab `spy()` function includes a fun little feature that I'm sure won't be replicated in R. Try submitting `spy()` with no arguments in Matlab.

Comment: @alexforrence: Excellent. Absolutely excellent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`image()` from [Matrix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/index.html) is one option.

```
library(Matrix)

# Example from ?Matrix:::sparseMatrix
i <- c(1,3:8); j <- c(2,9,6:10); x <- 7 * (1:7)
A <- sparseMatrix(i, j, x = x)

print(A)
##8 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

##[1,] . 7 . . .  .  .  .  .  .
##[2,] . . . . .  .  .  .  .  .
##[3,] . . . . .  .  .  . 14  .
##[4,] . . . . . 21  .  .  .  .
##[5,] . . . . .  . 28  .  .  .
##[6,] . . . . .  .  . 35  .  .
##[7,] . . . . .  .  .  . 42  .
##[8,] . . . . .  .  .  .  . 49

image(A)
```

[image]

---

To get the output of `spy()` in R, it takes a little bit more work.

In MATLAB (2011b):

```
spy()
h = gcf;
axObj = get(h, 'Children');
datObj = get(axObj, 'Children');

xdata = get(datObj,'XData');
ydata = get(datObj,'YData');
spyMat = [xdata; ydata];
csvwrite('spydat.csv',spyMat);
```

And in R:

```
library(Matrix)
spyData <- read.csv("spydat.csv")
spyMat <- t(sparseMatrix(spyData[1,],spyData[2,]))
image(spyMat)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple function that duplicates the Matlab spy() function in R, based on above ideas, is:

```
  library(Matrix)
  spy <- function(w){
    # Get indices not equal to zero
    inds <- which(w != 0, arr.ind=TRUE )
    # Create sparse matrix with ones where not zero
    A <- sparseMatrix(inds[,1], inds[,2], x = rep(1,nrow(inds)))
    # 
    image(A))
  }
```

This may be useful for some applications.